# Is it possible to delete all scope variable of a controller? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and i dont know is it possible to delete all scope variables of a controller.I am using ng-controller with ng-repeat, like this.

```
<div ng-controller="main">
<div ng-repeat="x in list" ng-controller="test">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text">
     <span ng-click="remove($index)">  x  </span>

<div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
myapp.controller('main',function($scope){

  $scope.list=[1,2,3,4]
})

myapp.controller('test',function($scope){
  $scope.text="untitiled"
})
```

I want to remove the clicked scope.Can anyone help me or please suggest me a better way. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean the clicked scope?  Do you just want the function to do nothing?

Comment: I think each element in the ng-repeat have different scope, I think its clear now what  clicked task means

Comment: `Removing the clicked scope` doesn't make much sense to me at all.  If you just want to do something else after you've clicked b/c the item has been removed that would make more sense.

Comment: Actually thats what i mean.sorry

Comment: Can you post the remove function's code?

Comment: hard to make any sense out of this question

Comment: The question isn't clear, but I answered what seems to be the general gist.  If he accepts it, I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't very clear, but it looks like you may want to remove the item after clicking.  Since you are passing into the `remove` function the index, you can splice it out.  The DOM will autoupdate and remove that from the list:

```
$scope.remove = function(i) {
   $scope.list.splice(i,1);
   console.log($scope.list);
}
```

In the event you are doing something different in that you only want to hide it, you would push the index onto another array and then use something like `ng-show` or `ng-hide`.

```
 $scope.remove2 = function(i) {
      $scope.hideList.push(i);  
   }

   $scope.shouldHide = function(i) {
      return $scope.hideList.indexOf(i)!=-1;
   }

<div ng-repeat="number in list2" >
 {{number}}
 <span ng-hide='shouldHide($index)' ng-click="remove2($index)">  x  </span>
</div>
```

Here is a simple example of both scenarios.  In real life, usually we are dealing with arrays of objects and what you might be doing is setting a property on one of the objects to hidden and controlling it that way.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/G7UINKUCBJ4yZhQNtuJ2?p=info

If you actually want to remove all the keys from the scope:

```
function removeKeys() {
  for(key in $scope) { 
   if (key.substr(0,1)!='$' && key!='this')
    delete $scope[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is with the controller. I am using the cotroller with ng-repeat